# Django ORM: Group by and SQL Agregation

Tags: sql, django, django-models, django-orm

I know that exists any same topics there, but that are not described my situation :(

I have a model below:

```
class SecurityPrice (models.Model):
    security    = models.ForeignKey(Security, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    created     = models.DateTimeField()
    price       = models.FloatField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s - %s - %s' % (self.created, self.security.ticker, self.price)
```

or in sqlite:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "restful_api_securityprice" 
("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
"created" datetime NOT NULL, 
"price" real NOT NULL, 
"security_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "restful_api_security" ("id"));
```

And I want to select last prices for each security paper

In raw SQL I may do it with such SQL-request:

```
SELECT MAX(created), security_id, price as created 
FROM restful_api_securityprice GROUP BY security_id;
```

**Below Some Examples for understand my needs:**

All records from table

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM restful_api_securityprice;
1|2018-01-07 23:13:02|920.0|1
2|2018-01-07 23:13:43|137.12|2
3|2018-01-07 23:13:58|147.3|3
4|2018-01-09 00:46:29|920.0|1
5|2018-01-09 00:47:27|137.12|2
6|2018-01-09 00:48:08|147.3|3
```

A what I to need

```
sqlite> SELECT MAX(created), security_id, price as created FROM restful_api_securityprice GROUP BY security_id;
2018-01-09 00:46:29|1|920.0
2018-01-09 00:47:27|2|137.12
2018-01-09 00:48:08|3|147.3
```

In raw SQL it's ok. But how I can do the same in Django ORM API without include raw sql?

Answer (score 0):

What about query like these:

```
SecurityPrice.objects.order_by('security', '-created').distinct('security')
```

Comment: May be, it will be a good point, but not for sqlite :( Django raise NotImplementedError exception: **DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend**

Comment: Ohh yeah. Time to switch to some more serious db like postgres?

Comment: Thanks, maybe on production I will take your advise. But for prototyping sqlite is very useful...